# How do I read values of registry keys?

Tags: powershell, windows-registry

Does anyone know how to read out registry key values in PowerShell?
The equivalent request in CMD can be seen on the picture.

[image: equivalent in CMD]

Answer (score 8):

Get-ChildItem is the one to use, and a quickie would be:

```
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion'
```

More examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/working-with-registry-keys

If you want to get a specific key value:

```
$val = (Get-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName').ComputerName
```

And how to set/edit appropriately
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/04/02/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/

Answer (score 7):

## `Get-ItemPropertyValue`

For registry operations, use:

- `Get-ItemProperty` and `Get-ItemPropertyValue` to read registry values and data
- `Get-Item` to get registry keys and sub-keys (but not to read registry values and data)
- `Get-ChildItem` to list sub-keys within keys and hives
- Optionally, use `New-PSDrive` to make registry drives (only HKCU and HKLM exist by default). Note you can also use long form without mounting (more details below)

For more information, see [Registry Provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_registry_provider).

## Example

Using your example as a starting point, which is using the *HKEY_USERS* registry root key, I'm going to lookup the *MenuBar* color, since the key you had was not available on my system.

### CMD

```
reg query "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Colors" /v MenuBar
```

### PowerShell

Using `Get-ItemPropertyValue`:

```
PS C:\> Get-ItemPropertyValue 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Colors' -Name MenuBar
240 240 240
```

Using `Get-ItemProperty`:

```
PS C:\> (Get-ItemProperty 'Registry::HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Colors').MenuBar
240 240 240
```

Using `New-PSDrive` to mount *HKEY_USERS* as *HKU*:

```
PS C:\> New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_USERS -Name HKU
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----
HKU                                    Registry      HKEY_USERS
PS C:\> Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKU:\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Colors' -Name MenuBar
240 240 240
PS C:\>
```

## Documentation

From [Registry Provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_registry_provider):

> The registry is divided into keys, subkeys, and entries. For more
>   information about registry structure, see [Structure of the Registry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/structure-of-the-registry).
>
> In a **Registry** drive, each key is a container. A key can contain any
>   number of keys. A registry key that has a parent key is called a
>   subkey. You can use `Get-ChildItem` to view registry keys and
>   `Set-Location` to navigate to a key path.
>
> Registry values are attributes of a registry key. In the **Registry**
>   drive, they are called **Item Properties**. A registry key can have both
>   children keys and item properties.
>
> ...
>
> Each registry key can also have subkeys. When you use Get-Item on a registry key, the subkeys are not displayed. The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet will show you children items of the "Spooler" key, including each subkey's properties. The parent keys properties are not shown when using `Get-ChildItem`.

From [Get-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item):

> This command shows the contents of the Microsoft.PowerShell registry key. You can use this cmdlet with the PowerShell Registry provider to get registry keys and subkeys, but you must use the `Get-ItemProperty` cmdlet to get the registry values and data.

Answer (score 1):

This format, while very similar can also be used:

```
$username = Get-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Volatile Environment"
```

Which creates an object.  The properties can be called using:

```
$username.username
```